# Finding nearest point using point dataset using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geocoding, nearest-neighbor, point-of-interest

I have created Geocode for some area and I couldn't find accurate Geocode's for few address. so I want to find the nearest POI for non accurated locations using accurated geocodes as referece in QGIS. I dont have any Road network also. Without road network i wanted to find it spatially.

How do i do that?

Comment: PostGIS provides solution see: http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor

Comment: can you add information about your dataset?

Comment: Its about address of some town in india. @ShahzadBacha

Comment: When i tried with PostGIS its giving random results for multiple records. Suggest me some solution using Postgre SQL. @Zoltan

Comment: By info what i mean is, do you have the geocoded points and non geocoded points in a single layer? @Chowdary

Comment: No, made it to two different layers and trying to find the nearest location for  non accurate locations @ShahzadBacha

Answer (score 1):

For a naive approach you can use this SQL select:

```
SELECT v.nev, f.nev, ST_Distance(v.geom, f.geom)
FROM varos AS v CROSS JOIN folyo AS f
WHERE (v.nev, 
ST_Distance(v.geom, f.geom)) in (
SELECT varos.nev, min(ST_Distance(varos.geom, folyo.geom)) 
FROM varos CROSS JOIN folyo
WHERE varos.nev = v.nev
GROUP BY varos.nev);
```

This Query selects the nearest city and river pairs (city = varos, river = folyo). You can speed up your query using <-> or <#> operator.

Comment: Does it gives street level locations or premise level location? @Zoltan